# OOP C++, virtual functions and new operator

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, virtual-functions

I have to write definition of the code below. I undarstand some basics of OOP Cpp, I know what is  `*x` or `&x`, but that's not enough... The main fact is that i cant understand line `B* p = new D, m, *k;` i cant understand what `m` and `*k` stand for.

```
class B {
  public: 
    virtual void msg() { cout << "classB"; }
};

class D: public B {
   public: 
     virtual void msg() { cout << "classD"; }
};

int main() {
  B* p = new D, m, *k;
  p->msg(); k = &m; k->msg();
  . . .
}
```

Help, if you can explain how (and **why** so) this code will work.

thanks, for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It declares multiple variables at once. This is basically the same as:

```
B *p = new D;
B  m;
B *k;
```

So `p` is a pointer to an instance of `D` allocated with new. `m` is a local instance of class `B` and `k` is a pointer to `B` that is later assigned to point at `m`.

The `msg` function is called on both allocated objects via the pointers `p` and `k`.

Note that `*` applies to each variable declaration separately. So `B* a, b;` doesn't declare two pointers, but instead declares one pointer and one local object. This is the reason, that many people prefer to write the `*` directly in front of the variable name: `B *a, b` makes this a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can declare more then one variable in one statement. Therefore `B* p = new D, m, *k;` declares the variables `p`, `m` and `k`. The `*` for pointer declarations binds to the variable name, therefore it's basically identical to

```
B* p = new D;
B m;
B* k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy, it's just plain old C.

```
B* p = new D, m, *k;
```

is just shortcut for:

```
B* p = new D;
B m;
B* k;
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer to an object of the class B (or D, because it is a child of the class B). `p->msg();` is similar to `(*p).msg();`. `m` is an object of the class B, so we can get pointer to it by `&` operator and store it in `k` (which is a pointer to an object of the class B).

And

```
B* p = new D, m, *k;
```

is just

```
B* p = new D;
B m;
B* k;
```

*Notice: you should put `*` if it is needed each time*